# Magento not rebuilding product image cache, certain pages loading with url extension ?_SID=U

Tags: magento, caching, permissions

site: cart.oldfloridian.com

After clearing Magento's image cache, the site seems unable to rebuild image caches and certain pages are loading with a url extension ?___SID=U.  All product images are coming up blank and look to be halting further loading of the site (no footer or sidebar loading on those pages).

It seems to be a permissions issue?  Relevant folder (media) is currently recursively set to 777.  But I'm still having issues.

I've read everything I could and found no solutions.  Changed memory allowance in php.ini.sample to 512M.  .htaccess does also have two areas that define this, set to 64M and 256M - would this change anything?

Any advice?

possibly this? - http://codepoets.co.uk/2011/magento-not-finding-product-images-solution/
I renamed folders (not files) manually, as I am a SQL newbie.  No change.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:

Alright, so my host returned the site to a backup from the day before I cleared the cache and at first that seemed to do something, but it has only returned certain images.  It looks like Magento is still unable to rebuild the cache, only now it has some stuff in the cache instead of being dead empty.  Should I try again all of those methods that previously had not worked?  Deleting the cache folder, etc etc?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and realized i forgot to install/enable gd library on my local server, it is a library responsible for image/thumbs cache recreation so check if gd2 is enabled in apache mudules

Comment: You saved my freaking life. This is the correct answer!

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/ is how to install it

Answer (score 1):

- media folder permission 777
- deleted htaccess file under the media folder
- clear the cache
- cache folder is writeable
- rebuilt all indexes

In my case I resolve renaming .htaccess in .htaccessOLD

Answer (score 0):

Check how much disk space is left.

I've experienced exact same symptoms before and it was because there was no disk space left to store new cache items.